# How do you open an embedded hyperlink in a PDF on an Android device?

Tags: applications, pdf

I have PDFs with hyperlinks (linking to other pages in the document as well as external websites) and would like to be able to use the links provided.  The Adobe Reader app and other apps I've tried (VuDroid, droidreader, android PDF reader) don't have this functionality.  I did find ezPDF which should work, but it is not free (only 99 cents).  I am looking for a way to do this for free because this is for an app I am writing that will need to display a PDF.  It will be much more appealing to the client - though still not perfect - if their users only have to download a free PDF reader, for example, to use with my app rather than requiring them to purchase a PDF reading app (even if it is only 99 cents).

Comment: Actually app recommendations are off-topic here. Try our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and please read the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Sorry about that.  The FAQ doesn't mention app recommendations and I can't post in the chat because I just signed up.  Is there a better place I can ask this?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. Since questions that ask "Is there an app that can do X?" get closed - I suggest you re-write the question to not ask for an app but instead a solution to your 'problem'.  Its one of those things I find odd about this site but makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - still trying to get the feel for things around here.

Comment: @Eric The problem is that app recommendations are more often subjective.  We get a lot of "What's the best PDF reader?" type questions, rather than ones with specific criteria like yours.  To make things simpler and to ensure better answers, we ask for "How can I do X?" questions instead which can be objectively answered. Even when the answers are probably going to be apps, it leaves it open to other solutions.  Presumably you would happily use open-source code to read and display PDFs with links inside your app -- but if that existed, it couldn't be provided as an answer to an app request.

Comment: The question (as it currently stands) is fine: How to open a link embedded in a PDF.

Comment: @Eric: I assume you've tried the usual long-press on the links to try to open them?

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the additional clarification.  I would be interested in using code to display and read PDFs with hyperlinks, but I haven't found anything that works/is well documented, so I'm focusing more on opening an app that will read the PDF.  But if there are any suggestions for code to use, I'm open to that as well.

Comment: @Al Yes, but with no success.  No context menu appears with a long press and the links do not open.

Comment: According to [this thread](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/303861-making-links-work-pdfs.html) this only works (so far) with Quick Office.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like [repligo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cerience.reader.app), [exPDF Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=udk.android.reader), [Quick Office](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qo.android.am3) and [Documents to Go](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dataviz.docstogoapp) support hyperlinks...unfortunately all paid apps.

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader) can follow hyperlinks in PDF documents.

The problem (currently, 2014-09-17) is that the default application associated with PDF documents is Quickoffice, and Quickoffice doesn't have this implemented.
Installing Adobe Reader allows you to choose (and optionally remember your choice) what app to use.